# Problems with the body element in Foundation 4 in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I'm creating a site with the foundation framework 4 and I have to support IE8, this works well in modern browsers.

I found a place to provide a foundation 4 grid for IE8, When I change the browser size the body adjusts to the browser but it is behind the content and this is not it wrapped and do not know how to fix it.

[image: The body move]
[image: The body move and no wrap the content]

Here I leave the link to be seen: (Try it in IE8) I use Virtual Box to emulate IE8
http://www.pruebas.chaloman.com/recomendacion/

The code I use for foundation 4 work on IE8 is in the following link:
https://gist.github.com/hatefulcrawdad/5068210

UPDATE:

I start coding again with bootstrap 2.3.2 and dont have any styles and the problem persist en firefox 24 inclusive, see the image, this happens when i rezize de browrser.

Please see the another example here and help me:
http://www.pruebas.chaloman.com/boots/

[image: The body moves inclusive in firefox 24 i dont have any style only the default boostrap styles]

Comment: You mean when the user shrinks the window, the content doesn't shrink with it like in other browsers? I can reproduce that. But hundreds of lines of HTML is a bit much to debug. Can you make a smaller example, that demonstrates the problem but doesn't contain anything irrelevant to the issue?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer, i add some pictures with the problem,

Answer (score 0):

Your source code is bit lengthy..
Try this one...
In your html head

```
    <!-- Foundation 3 for IE 8 and earlier -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation3/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation3/foundation.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation3/app.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Foundation 4 for IE 9 and earlier -->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation4/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation4/foundation.css">
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

And after the close body tag:

```
   <!-- Foundation 3 for IE 8 and earlier -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="/js/foundation3/foundation.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/foundation3/app.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->

   <!-- Foundation 4 for IE 9 and later -->
   <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
   <script src="/js/foundation4/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).foundation();
   </script>
   <!--<![endif]-->
```

for more see this link http://zurb.com/article/1204/getting-foundation-and-ie8-to-play-nice

Comment: Thanks chinmayahd , i start to coding again finding the error and using bootstrap 2.3.2 the error continues. See the example

Answer (score 0):

## **I solved**

I found the solution to my problem, I use the min-width property and give you a value.
The solution is for fixed width.

i use:

```
body {
min-width: 960px; /*fixed width*/
}
```